# How to prevent consumers of my library to install my devDependencies?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json, package-managers, pnpm

I've a library which has a `peerDependency`. In order to be able to work on the library, I have also listed it as a `devDependency`:

```
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "foo": "^3.0 || ^4.0"
  },
  "devDependency": {
    "foo": "^4.0"
  }
}
```

I've received reports of consumers saying that even though they have installed `foo@^3.0`, my package is pulling `foo@^4.0`, so now their projects have a mix of both 3 and 4.

I was under the assumption that since `foo` is declared on peer, it wouldn't be installed for consumer projects, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

We've consider adding `--prod` flags on consumer project, but that means we'd need to force them to use it: "in order to use our library, you need to install with --prod or risk having a mix of both packages" I'm not sure this is the best approach.

What am I missing, is there a way to make my library don't pull devDependencies that are declared on peerDependenceis when consumer run install?

If it helps, we're using [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) as our package manager

Comment: Try `npm`: `yarn`, `npm` and `pnpm` support peerDep in different manner. You may [read here](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/1780#issuecomment-517294071) to go deeper

Comment: We had to move our previous package manager to `pnpm` because of pnpm workspaces. Can't really go back. What I take from the link above is that I should be using `--production` flag always (?)

Comment: I don't understand what Manuel means about pnpm supporting peer deps in a different manner. When we were adding support for peer dependencies, we were using the same approach that npm uses. The linked issue is unrelated to peer dependencies. It is an issue with fastify plugins relying on flat node_modules. 

Regarding your issue, pnpm NEVER installs dev dependencies of dependencies (same as yarn and npm), it doesn't matter that foo is a peer dep. foo will not be installed unless it is a regular dependency.

Comment: The ranges in peer dependencies are not used during installation, they are just used to check whether the dependencies that were already installed match them.

Feel free to write in our discord chatroom or file issues in our repository

Comment: @ZoltanKochan You're right, I ran a test by altering node-modules. I think my problem might be related to the CSS loader, perhaps it's loading my dependencies dev-dependency stylesheet rather than the project's